# array ng-repeat checkbox with form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

[image]
  i want to retrive checkbox value on submit event.i am using mongodb database.console i am getting value like this Tyres,Spares,Accessories.i have made view page based on output.if when i click check box i got error in console
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'selected' of 'tyres'.how could i solve this please some one help me out

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc object
 * @name test1.Controllers.Test1Controller
 * @description Test1Controller
 * @requires ng.$scope
 */
angular
    .module('test1')
    .controller('Test1Controller', [
        '$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window',
        function($scope, $http, $location, $window) {

            $http.get('***').success(function(data, status, response) {
                $scope.items = (JSON.stringify(data[0].D_Services).replace(/\"/g, "")).split(',');
                console.log($scope.items);
            });

            $scope.check = function(items) {
                console.log(items);
            };
        }
    ]);
```

```html
<div ng-controller="Test1Controller" data-ng-init="loadservice()">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'" /> {{item}}
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" ng-click="check(items)" />
</div>
```

```
how can i grab all selected check box values on submit action only
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result of this code: `items.split(',')` is an array that does not exists in scope, so it cannot be a writable model for ng-repeat directive. You should create an array in your scope like this:

```
$scope.items = (JSON.stringify(data[0].D_Services).replace(/\"/g, "")).split(',');
```

and use this model in markup

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    ...
</div>
```

If you need result as a string, you should join it before returning:

```
$scope.check = function(items) {
   console.log(items.join(','));
};
```

Comment: thanks i have changed my code.<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected"  ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'"/> {{item}}
</div>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" ng-click="check()"/>    .how can i take only selected values on submit event

Comment: Use 'map' method to convert 'items' array to format like this: [ { value: 'Tyres', selected: false },... ]. and bind checkbox text to 'item.value' like this: {{item.value}} . Than you can filter your values by 'filter' method before sending.

Comment: PS: Just google for Array.prototype.map() and Array.prototype.filter() if you don`t know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

since items is an string like

```
var items = "john,grace,peter";
```

and when you perform items.split(',') it will result and array of strings like

```
["john","grace","peter"]
```

and when ng-model trys to set checked status for each element which is error because you can't do operations like

```
items[1].selected
```

since items[1] is an array.

Comment: how can i take selected values on submit event